# Error inserting a document in a MongoDB sharded collection created with the CLI

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb, sharding

Using the latest azure cli (2.0.21) I am trying to create in CosmosDB a sharded MongoDB collection with the following script (from powershell) :

```
$resourceGroupName="RG-S01-APP-CASRWA-001"
$name="marcoolandesetest"
$databaseName="marco"
$collectionName="fromcli"
$originalThroughput=100000 
$kind="MongoDB"
$partition="/TaskId"

az login
az cosmosdb create --name $name --kind $kind --resource-group 
$resourceGroupName

az cosmosdb database create --name $name --db-name $databaseName --resource-
group $resourceGroupName 

az cosmosdb collection create --collection-name $collectionName --name $name --db-name $databaseName --resource-group $resourceGroupName --throughput $originalThroughput --partition-key-path $partition --indexing-policy '@index.json'
```

The content of the index.json is the following:

```
{
    "indexingMode": "consistent",
    "automatic": true,
    "includedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/*",
            "indexes": [
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "Number",
                    "precision": -1
                },
                {
                    "kind": "Hash",
                    "dataType": "String",
                    "precision": 3
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "excludedPaths": []
}
```

But when I try to insert a document from the UI in the portal nothing happens, the document hangs on inserting:

[image]

Inserting a document from a C# library with the MongoB.Drivers nuget package also fails, getting the error:

"document does not contain shard key"

**obviously my document contains the shard key property "TaskId"**.

**If I create the same kind of collection from the UI in the Portal everything works fine, also in C#, using the same code**

Here are two screenshots of the settings of the collections, as you can see they are the same:

[image]

[image]
Collection "fromui" is created from the portal UI, and with this one everything works fine, inserting a document from the portal, and inserting from C# as well.

Collection "fromcli" is created using the CLI script above and inserting a document it's not working at all.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft confirmed there is a bug in the CLI (2.0.21), they will soon roll out an update.

I created a blog post to describe how to solve this until a new CLI version will be release with a fix:

https://blog.olandese.nl/2017/12/13/create-a-sharded-mongodb-in-azure-cosmos-db/

Comment: Fixed my problem, thanks. Do you know if their fix will break code using this solution when it rolls out?

Answer (score 0):

Which browser do you use to create new document in the Portal? Could you please try to use another browser (Edge, Firefox, Chrome, Safari) or clean the browser cache completely and retry?

Comment: This behavior is not caused due a browser issue, this happens also from code, i.e. C#, it's a "server side" issue.

Comment: The part where you describe hanging "Creating new document" message in the browser is definitely a browser issue and is fixed by cleaning browser cache.