# How to create a partitioned Azure MongoDB collection with the CLI?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cli

Microsoft documentation for [`az cosmosdb collection create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/cosmosdb/collection?view=azure-cli-latest#az-cosmosdb-collection-create)
says that `--partition-key-path` can be used to name a key to use for a collection. In this case, it's a "MongoDB" collection:

```
name='myName'
databaseName='myDatabase'
resourceGroupName='myRg'
collectionName='myCollection'

echo "Create database account"
az cosmosdb create --name $name --kind MongoDB --locations "Central US"=0 --resource-group $resourceGroupName

echo "Create database"
az cosmosdb database create --name $name --db-name $databaseName --resource-group $resourceGroupName

echo "Create collection $collectionName"
az cosmosdb collection create --name $name --db-name $databaseName --resource-group $resourceGroupName --collection-name $collectionName --partition-key-path '/partition'
```

What do I need to change to avoid the following error and create a partitioned collection?

```
Create database account
...
Create database
...
Create collection myCollection
ERROR: Operation Failed: Invalid Arg {"Errors":["The partition key component definition path
'C:\/Apps\/Git\/partition' could not be accepted, failed near position '0'. Partition key paths must contain only
valid characters and not contain a trailing slash or wildcard character."]}
```

Comment: Just to make sure we are on the same page. You are creating a database account and then a collection. Are you also creating a database before that?

Comment: @NickChapsas - Yes, sorry. I'll update the question.

Comment: The error is basically a misunderstanding of powershell thinking you are points at a disk path. That's why you get `C:\/Apps\/Git\/partition` in the error. Did you try replacing single quotes with double one for the path? It's just a guess. Basically anything that will make the system understand that this is not a path to a folder will work

Comment: @NickChapsas- I've tried double-quotes and also tried it without quotes. I'm dropping and re-creating everything right now, but I'll retry that shortly.

Comment: I'll give it a go as well. I wonder, if you parameterise it the same way you did with the other properties, will it throw the error?

Comment: @NickChapsas - Also worth a shot.

Comment: Just tested on windows cmd and double quotes did the trick for me. Which environment are you running this on?

Comment: @NickChapsas - Ugh, made progress. My script was based on this bash script: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/scripts/create-mongodb-database-account-cli?toc=%2fcli%2fazure%2ftoc.json. If I change the single quotes to double _and_ run just the command in the cmd shell, it works. Preceding the command with `cmd /C` just seems to hang.

Comment: @NickChapsas - I'm also on windows, but in a MinGW bash prompt. :)

Comment: It's at a point where I can't confidently tell you what it might be, but it doesn't sound like a problem with the CLI itself or your command but rather the way bash tries to run.

Comment: Agreed. I'll tinker with it some more. If I figure out anything, I'll let you know, but you've got me in the right direction. Now we just need to figure out something for you to put in answer so I can accept it. :)

Comment: Sounds good, I'm so curious to know what it was after all so just let me know when you figure it out.

Comment: @NickChapsas - This, amazingly, works: `cmd "/C az cosmosdb collection create --name $name --db-name $databaseName --resource-group $resourceGroupName --collection-name $collectionName --partition-key-path "/partition""`

Comment: And don't escape the inner quotes, for whatever reason.

Comment: That is so weird. Anyway, I'm glad it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after all the back and forth it appears to be a path escaping issue, where the partition key, when provided with single quotes, was assumed to be a folder from bash.

However changing single quotes to double quotes worked.

When tried to run with `cmd /C` the following seems to be working.

`cmd "/C az cosmosdb collection create --name $name --db-name $databaseName --resource-group $resourceGroupName --collection-name $collectionName --partition-key-path "/partition""`

Comment: Nick, check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47591635/error-inserting-a-document-in-a-mongodb-sharded-collection-created-with-the-cli?rq=1